# Is it possible to locate a file outside of heroku app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, heroku, deployment

I've deployed a git repo to heroku. However, my app uses files that are located outside of the project folder to ensure more security.

In my `index.js` I have something like this

```
const credentials = require('../credentials/someCredentials.json');
...
```

I have `index.js` in the root of my git repo and I have `credentials` folder outside my git repo

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: @MattFletcher what do you mean by that? I have no problems deploying my git repo, but my app fails due to absence  of some imports that are not on heroku

Comment: Just wondering what kind of error you are getting

Comment: @MattFletcher on Heroku there's no file under this path `../credentials/someCredentials.json`

Comment: If, by credentials, you mean token id, client id etc, you should probably add those to the dyno environment variables via the heroku dashboard.

Comment: @Andy thank you I'll give it a try, I didn't know about it

Comment: @JohnAward, just checked; they're called config variables and you can add them on the settings page.